Teen movie with a party and a funeral at the same time
Ok, here it goes:
group of students are planning to have a party behind the principals back. A funeral of a deceased student is due the same date as the party, therefore the principal believes it's just a plot the students concocted. The principal goes to the funeral, ruins it and gets beaten by dead student's angry family.
Meanwhile at the party two large african american students discuss on adult movies while group of students stare admiringly. The main characters cook pancakes (or crepes suzettes). In the end the principal finds out where the party actually is, but main character's mother saves the day by lying to the principal, that they were at the funeral (or elsewhere, I don't remember).

Sounds like you're after Senior Skip Day from 2008 with Lea Thompson and Tara Reid.

When Adam accidentally gives up the location for the senior skip day party to his school's principal, he offers up his house as a new location. But for it to be a success, he needs to get his senior class to his house and stop the principal from crashing the party.

The principal goes to the funeral and goes as far as opening the casket, thinking there's beer inside. He's wrong, of course. Here's the trailer:




Thank you so much! This is the movie I was looking for :)
